# Invoking else statement every time

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is My code for adding a order details to the database. I want to check whether Stock Amount is higher or lower than Order Amount.So i put if statements on this. But every time it Invoke else statement. What is the wrong with this code

It Always Invoke Else Statement

```
function OrderAdd() {


            var INameO = $("#INanme").text();
            var IpriceO = $("#IPrice").text();
            var IquantityO = $("#OQuntity").val();// order Amount
            var Oquantity = $('#IQuantity').text(); //stock Amount
            var Total = $("#IPrice").text() * $("#OQuntity").val();

                if(Oquantity>IquantityO) {

                    addOrder(INameO, IpriceO, IquantityO, Total);
                    viewAllOrders();
                    gettotal();
                    clearItemArea();
                    console.log(IquantityO);
                    console.log(Oquantity);
                }
                else {alert("Amount exceeded")
                }
      }
```

```
function gettotal() {

     var temptotal = 0;
    var temp = getAllOrders();
    for (var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
        var Total = temp[i].getOtotal();
        temptotal = temptotal+Total;
        $('#totalP').text(temptotal);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your input value? What is stock value?

Comment: `console.log` the `IquantityO` and `Oquantity` and check what values you are getting before `if` statement.

Comment: Do you know how to use your debugger?

Comment: Order Amount and Stock amount are added by run time.

Comment: i checked values before if statements.they are same as after values.

Comment: Have you looked into whether you are running into a type conversion problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is a one error. I didn't change values to the INT type. That's Why else Statement Invoking  Every time. You can understand Better after watching this code.

```
 function OrderAdd() {


        var INameO = $("#INanme").text();
        var IpriceO = parseInt( $("#IPrice").text());
        var Oquantity =parseInt( $('#IQuantity').text()); //stock Amount
        var IquantityO = parseInt($("#OQuntity").val());// order Amount
        var Total = $("#IPrice").text() * $("#OQuntity").val();


            //findduplicates(INameO);
            if (Oquantity>IquantityO){
            addOrder(INameO, IpriceO, IquantityO, Total);
            viewAllOrders();
            gettotal();
            clearItemArea();
             }
            else{alert("Amount exceeded!")
            }
        }
```